# KML files no longer showing data for point location - shows placement pin

Tags: kml

We do gps-based point soil sampling and have software designed for that. Our software allows us to export a KML file that has all the attributes of the soil samples on it. They pop up and show all attributes on my PC version of Google Earth. A few months ago, it worked the same way on my iPhone app - Touch on a push pin and the attributes pop up. Now, they no longer show up on the iPhone app. Any ideas why not? Same files works good on my PC.